# How to avoid setters using Symfony with admin panel creator?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, dto

I want to avoid getters/setters hell in my entities (here is the reason: http://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/53), but both most popular admin panel generators:

- Sonata and DoctrineORMAdminBundle
- https://github.com/javiereguiluz/EasyAdminBundle

need getters and setters to render view.

My idea is to create DTO object instead (http://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/57) and then use named constructors to create entities. I want to call named constructor inside my service. What is the best way to force admin panel generators to use my DTOs to persist/update data, can you give me an idea and/or example of good practices in that case?

The only way I imagined is to use DTO instead of real Entity, call prePersist/preUpdate hooks and use custom service, but it looks confusing.

Comment: About the only way to force most crud generators not to use getters/setters is to not use the crud generators.  I sympathize with your desire to not use getters/setters.  I don't like them either.  But getting rid of them basically means writing you own software,  And of course be careful what you read on the internet.  Your link has some good points as well as some very bad ones ("eager loading is useless"!!!).  Nor does he indicate how to use dto's with the form component.

Comment: Good question and interesting slides, but I'm not sure DTO can replace entities in all cases . You can surely find alternatives with SonataAdminBundle, it allows you to do custom query for listing. I don't really know what say about avoiding setters in create/edit forms. The pre/post hooks will work but it's limited.
See this interesting issue in Sonata https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataDoctrineORMAdminBundle/issues/501 , there is examples of DTO implementation.

Comment: @Cerad did you see who made this presentation? It's Ocramius - inventor of Doctrine. If you see his whole presentation you will fully agree with him. You can find it here: https://vimeo.com/134178140

Comment: @sredni - I do know the author, have watched the presentation several times and have a great deal of respect for his opinions.  However, this particular question deals with CRUD type applications using CRUD generating tools.  His DTO based approach is simply not applicable.

Comment: @Cerad maybe becouse of that CRUD excludes DDD and vice versa

Comment: @Cerad The DDD tactical patterns are mutually exclusive to CRUD, but the essence of DDD is its strategic patterns, not the tactical ones and those may lead you to determine that all you need is CRUD within some Bounded Contexts. Trying to use the domain model pattern everywhere would just show a misunderstanding of what DDD is about...

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important aspect of DDD is to correctly identify your bounded contexts (usually aligned with your sub-domains) and determine the appropriate technologies and architectures to use within those.

An admin panel sounds like something generic that would be very CRUD in nature. If that's the case then don't try to fight it and embrace CRUD within that BC. Trying to implement a pure domain model in a BC where it isn't needed would make things more complicated than they need to be.

However, if you determined that the complexity justifies a domain model then I would advise against using a code generator. Properly modeling the reality of a complex domain is not an easy task, and certainly not one that could be achieved by a tool.